# getting a reference to UIVIEW CONTROLLER

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiprogressview

I need to update a progress bar from view controller lets call him A which is located in view controller B , the update is done when I start a NSULRCONNECTION from B that will access the method `DidSendBodyData` defined in view controller A in this method there is the progress bar that should be updated, here is my code in view controller B :

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController * myStoryboardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

HomeViewController *rootViewController = [myStoryboardInitialViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                initWithRequest:request
                                delegate:rootViewController startImmediately:NO];
```

this is the code defined in class B, I need reference to view controller A which is here `rootViewController`
but what is done above is not right because it creates another object of the view controller and not using the existing one which means that a new progress bar will be created and updated and that is not what I want,I need to update the existing one in view controller A

here is my code in view controller A :

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{
 (float)totalBytesWritten ,(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite); 
 [progress setProgress:((float)(totalBytesWritten))/totalBytesExpectedToWrite];   
}
```

when the connection is established the method `didsendBodyData` is called in view controller A and the progress bar should be updated.

how can I get a reference to view controller A without creating new view controller ?!

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to ask for a reference to another class - you want to *delegate* the work of updating the progress.

Create a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) and have your first controller implement it. Ensure that you a) have a delegate and b)your delegate responds yo your progress updates and you are golden